# How to use scp with xargs?

Tags: linux, unix, command, scp, xargs

I am trying to move very big file from one host to another host. Also the file names are too large so I have to use `xargs`. Also all the sub directories need to be copied also

I am using the below command in the source host current directory

```
find . -name "*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 scp -r UserName@host:/path/to/destination
```

but it is throwing below error

```
scp: /path/to/destination: not a regular file
```

Answer (score 8):

you need to use {} to put the src filename before the destination. Here is the new command:

```
find . -name "*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} scp -r {} UserName@host:/path/to/destination
```

Comment: Almost there, but one thing I need that sub-directories should be also copied.. but for now only the contents of the sub directories are being moved. Secondly, the command is asking for password every time it copies one file. Any solution?

Comment: if you want directories to be copied then remove the -f parameter from the find command. if you do not want to type in passwords all the time then add your public ssh id to the remote machine and use ssh-agent to store your key on the machine you ru. the command from.

Comment: So I removed `-f` and the files of sub-directories are getting copied twice. One time on the `/path/to/destination` and again `/path/to/destination/source_folder/`. I hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: Well this seems to be a whole different issue. You should post another question detailing your problem with examples and someone will answer it